# Is f(X)=X+a exponentially distributed when X is exponential R.V and a>0?

Tags: probability, random-variables, linear-transformations, exponential-distribution

Suppose $X$ is an exponential R.V with parameter $\lambda$. Then, I am interested to find the distribution of $f(X)=X+a$, for $a>0$. To this end, I have computed the following:
$$\Bbb E\left[f(X)\right]=a+1/\lambda$$ and $${\rm Var}\left(f(X)\right)=1/\lambda^2$$
Since ${\rm Var}\left(f(X)\right)\neq \left(\Bbb E\left[f(X)\right]
\right)^2$ which is usually the case for an exponential r.v, I suspect that $f(X)$ is not an exponential r.v. Am I correct in my conjecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y:=X+a$, then \begin{align}F_{Y}(y)=P(Y\le y)=P(X+a\le y)=P(X\le y-a)=F_X(y-a)\end{align} Hence \begin{align}f_{Y}(y)&=\frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_X(y-a)=f_X(y-a)=λe^{-λ(y-a)}\end{align} for $a<y$. This is called the *shifted exponential distribution* with shift $a$. Intuitively your "exponential life" starts at time $a$ and not at time $0$.

Comment: I think you meant $Y:=X+a$. Also, with this definition of $Y$, $a<y$ always holds because $X>0$. Right?

Comment: @statnewbie Yes, of course, I mean X+a. Yes, ok, actually formally the exponential is also defined for X<0, but f(x)=0 for x<0. So, yes, if we only take X>0 then it is basically immediate as you say.